# What would be best query for this mass delete?

Tags: mysql, database

Currently I am doing mass deletes using variations of the following query:

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.key NOT IN (SELECT t2.key FROM t2)
```

I am told that sub queries too slow in MySQL and the should be optimized.  But I cannot find a better example.  Is it possible to do a join and delete?

Comment: maybe do it in chunks using limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM t1 USING t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.key = t2.key LIMIT 1000;
```

And repeat until nothing is left, this allows not blocking table for a long time.

UPD: but if you need to join on the same table this solution will not work.

UPD2: I overlooked the `NOT`, here is the corrected query:

```
DELETE FROM t1
USING t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE t2.key IS NULL
LIMIT 1000;
```

I should note that this is the case where the subquery would perform at the same speed as the JOIN, look into a [good post](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) of [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) about the issue.

Comment: For further information see: [DELETE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) along with [JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (table_references). Sorry for my unforgivable error before.

Comment: @newtover : in my case I am deleting entries that DON'T exist in t2. Can you tell me if a variation of your query will work in that case?